# Chrome storage API not working in MV3 for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm having troubles getting chrome storage API to work in MV3. I've tried this so far and even in the service worker console it returns an undefined result

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'test': 'test' }, function() {
        chrome.storage.local.get('test', function(result) {
            console.log('Value currently is ' + result);
        });
    });
```

Here is my manifest I'm not sure if that's an issue

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "NAME",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
     }, 
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {             
          "16": "favicon.ico"         
        },
        "default_title": "Outboundly",  
        "default_popup": "index.html" 
    },  
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "scripting",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",     
        "unlimitedStorage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]  
}
```

I've also tried it in the content script and within the popup context as well.

Comment: The code is almost correct, one thing to fix is to replace `+` with `,` in console.log to output objects properly. Make sure you've reloaded the extension. It can be also a bug in Chrome, so try to uninstall the extension and install it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but I changed the position of the permissions around in the manifest, and that seemed to have fixed things. Possibly a bug.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "NAME",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
     },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "scripting",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",     
        "unlimitedStorage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"] 
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {             
          "16": "favicon.ico"         
        },
        "default_title": "Outboundly",  
        "default_popup": "index.html" 
    }  
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Should you call in `['test']`?

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

[reference](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage)